# mysql where between like and like query error i had receive error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database and i want to get dates between. my code is

```
SELECT * FROM `cdr`  
WHERE  BETWEEN calldate LIKE '2014-08-28%' 
AND LIKE '2014-08-27%'
```

But not works...

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `cdr`  
WHERE  BETWEEN calldate '2014-08-28% 
AND '2014-08-27'
```

But not worked because the column is y.m.d - h.m.s

Anyone help me ? thanks

Comment: what's the type of the column, varchar/text or datetime? If it's datetime then like won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your query in [***`Sargable way`***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) by providing hard coded time start/end values

```
SELECT * FROM `cdr`  
where  calldate between '2014-08-27 00:00:00' and '2014-08-28 11:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

`where foo between bar and baz` is the equivalent of

```
WHERE (foo >= bar) AND (foo <= baz)
```

It has never been, and never will be, capable of doing a `LIKE` comparison. You can *NOT* finagle your query to ever work.

As well, you're trying to do the between backwards. It's `foo BETWEEN lower_value AND higher_value`.

All you need is

```
WHERE calldate BETWEEN '2014-08-27' AND '2014-08-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend avoiding `between` on dates, particularly when there are time values.  Here is an approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM `cdr`  
WHERE calldate >= date('2014-08-27') and
      calldate < date('2014-08-27') + interval 1 day;
```

All the functions are on the constant, so this query can make use of an index on `cdr(calldate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `cdr` WHERE `calldate` BETWEEN '2014-08-09%' AND '2014-08-10%'
```

> NOTE: BETWEEN's clause 1st string should be less than 2nd one.